# How a photon choose a geodesic?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, geodesics

Suppose we have two point $p$ and $q$ linked by two geodesics $\gamma_1$ and $\gamma_2$. Now suppose that a photon is emitted at $p$ and received at $q$. How does the photon choose which of the geodesics to follow?

Comment: The geodesic equation is a differential equation, and its solution requires the specification of the initial conditions. Thus, when Umaxo said bellow that it is emitted with a certain 4-velocity, this 4-velocity is the initial condition that someone (or some mechanism) chose. Thus, the choice of initial condition is picking either $\gamma_1$ or $\gamma_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If particle is emitted, it is emitted with certain 4-velocity and it follows geodesic for which this is tangent vector. The decision is completely local, photon has no apriori desire to travel to some point q and then looks for the geodesic to follow.

That being said, photon is quantum mechanical object and such does not follow any particular geodesic.

Comment: I'd say that for a photon, in momentum representation, each momentum component travels at its own geodesic.

Comment: "Photon" is just a subspace of the number operator on EM field states. There is plenty degrees of freedom (3 of the 4-momentum) and all possible superpositions, that include multiple spatially distinct wave-packets, that all still bare the name "a single photon". That is, if you have "1 photon" state with k and "1 photon" state with k', any superposition of those is still under "1 photon" subspace. Thus generalizes with any number of components.

Comment: (1) Take a single photon, pass it through 10 beam splitters and you will get ~10 wave packets, spatially distinct, all of them together represent the same photon. (This is the actual action of beam splitters, as low energy photons practically don't interacts, so it splits the beam photon by photon). The detector will make a click at certain specific path. Repeat many times to recover the distribution of paths taken.

Comment: (2) I didn't feel the need to fill all the details. Take single photon wavepacket around k and k' and superpose them. For further questions I advise you to read on second quantization of EM fields, as in any quantum optics book. Emphasis on current experimental methods shed light too on the "photon" concept.

Comment: @Alexander Sorry, I have no idea what is your point. But I am getting warning to avoid extended discussions, so let us end it.

Answer (score 1):

Beside "position" photons also have "momentum". Both impose initial position and direction of propagation. There are no two geodesics that have same direction at the same position.